# lstlisting environment inside luacode

Tags: listings, luatex, lua, luacode

I'd like to feed a lstlisting environment (from the `listings` package) with contents back to TeX from Lua, but the end of lstlisting is apparently not found.  The same happens if lstlisting is replaced with verbatim.  How do I fix this?

*Note that I want luacode to feed lstlisting back to TeX, not a hack that works in this instance but doesn't do that.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}

\newcommand{\processfile}[1]{\directlua{processfile("#1")}}

\begin{luacode*}
function processfile(fn)
  tex.print("\\begin{lstlisting}\n")
  local f=assert(io.open(fn,"r"))
  local t= f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  tex.print(t)
  tex.print("\\end{lstlisting}\n")  
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\processfile{code.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative: Write your changes to a file and use lstinputlisting (indirectly feeding it).

Comment: Does  `tex.print("\\scantokens{\end{lstlisting}\n")` help?

Comment: Actually, I want to process the input in Lua and stick parts in lstlisting environments interspersed with LaTeX.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: nope

Comment: @TeXnician: That's one I had actually thought of....  thanks, but no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work. But I had to use the luacode-environment. So it not "pure" luacode but I didn't find a way to do the \detokenize on the lua-side. I also changed the processing to line-by-line to get the correct linebreak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\processfile}[1]{\directlua{processfilebyline("#1")}}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function processfilebyline(fn)
  tex.print("\\begin{lstlisting}")
  local f=assert(io.open(fn,"r"))
  while true do
      local line = f:read("*line")
      if line == nil then break end
      tex.print(line)
    end
  f:close()
  tex.print("\detokenize{\\end{lstlisting}}")
  end

\end{luacode}
 %
\begin{document}
\processfile{duck.tex}
\end{document}
```